# Как починить сайт на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Правил файл в режиме HTML templates-maincomponents-bitrixcatalog.section.default-template.php

Добавил текст, потом его удалил. Но что-то развалилось.

Каталог выдает ошибку на сайте Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in httpdocs/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/catalog.section/.default/template.php on line 20

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ваш вопрос получит ответ, если вы хотя бы скинете исходный код тех файлов, в которых вызывается ошибка: `template.php`

Answer (score 1):

Php файлы нельзя редактировать в режиме html!

Вот здесь лежит исходный код, который должен быть в файле template.php, если этот файл не редактировался.

```
Корень_сайта /bitrix/components/bitrix/catalog.section/templates/.default/template.php
```